# Adding autocomplete="off" to inputs rendered through jquery.load() through an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

In a gigantic MVC 1.0 application I've been maintaining, we decided that we want to turn autocomplete off for every input field in the application.  Thousands of them.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

But the issue I'm having is that in certain places, I've got partials whose content is being requested via AJAX and loaded through `.load`.  I tried setting autocomplete off after ajaxComplete, but that doesn't work either, since the .load isn't until after the ajax request is finished.  Is there a global `.loadComplete` sort of event that I can watch for so I don't have to fire off the autocomplete function in every `load` callback?

Here's how I load the partial:

```
$('#PaymentContent').load('/Payment/ACHPartial',function() {
....
})
```

how I tried with ajaxsuccess before:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching a global handler for the ajaxComplete event, getting the content that is about to be loaded, and manipulate it:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(event,xhr,settings) {
        xhr.responseText = 
        $(xhr.responseText).filter("input").attr('autocomplete', 'off').get(0);
});
```

This way, you would be manipulating the contents before they are loaded in the html. Not tested though!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm, that definitely seems like it could work, although I've never done anything like it before.  I tried pasting that in, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've edited the OP with an example of how I'm rendering a partial if it will help

Comment: I missed actually updating the responseText! check the edited answer, it might give you an idea. My intention is to build a jquery object with the response text, change the inputs attribute, and then replace the actual response text with the "updated" one from the jquery object.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I definitely see what you're trying to do.  That still doesn't seem to be working though.  I'm not getting any errors, but it's just not doing anything

Comment: hmmm, apparently it doesn't work that way. The content is loaded even before the global ajaxComplete event. the only thing I can think of is selecting the inputs in the global ajaxComplete handler and setting autocomplete off. It should consider the newly loaded ones.

Comment: Hmm, okay, well definitely thanks for the help.  I tried doing that in the ajaxComplete Handler but it still didn't seem to work.  Updated OP with my old attempt